# Can I get RNetLogo to see a monitor value in order to run?

Tags: r, loops, netlogo

I have a model built in NetLogo which I want to run through R with the RNetLogo package. I have a simple piece of code to run the model for 100 ticks as follows:

```
nruns <- 100 
NLCommand("setup")
for (i in 1:nruns)NLCommand("go")
turtlecoords <- list()
turtlecoords[[i]] <- NLGetAgentSet(c("who","xcor","ycor"), "turtles")
turtlecoords[[i]]
```

This works fine but I want to be able to get the model to run for a certain amount of days which counted on a monitor that I've created in the NetLogo model. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I've figured it out by using a global variable called day in NetLogo and using that to set the length of time that the model runs with `NLDoCommandWhile("day < 10",  "go")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetLogo monitor is just a widget which evaluates some NetLogo reporter.
You can evaluate expression used in monitor with `RNetLogo::NLReport` function.

For example

```
NLReport("ticks * 24")
```

will return the number of iterations multiplied by 24.

In R use `while` loop or use `break` to escape from `for` or `repeat` loop.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying that the monitor is just a widget. If I code something up like `set day-length = 24000` in NetLogo, could I call on that?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question, but yes - in the reporter expression you can use any global variable. Global variables could be declared and set by sliders or declared in `globals` keyword and assigned with `set`.